# How to dynamically instantiate a protobuf object with oneof fields

Tags: python, reflection, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message defined something like this

```
message data {
  user string = 1;
  oneof event {
     server.login login = 1;
     server.register register = 2;
     server.delete delete = 3;
  }
}
```

Now I have a function in python

```
def create_data_object(self, event)
```

Now the event could instance of the protos

```
server.login
server.register
server.delete
```

Now depending upon the type of proto it is like login,register or delete I want to create a data object something like

```
dataobject = data(user="someuser", {type}=event)
```

where type needs to be determined from the passed event object.

Now note that I can do it with something like

```
type = event.DESCRIPTOR.full_name
```

And then use some sort of switch condition and instantiate the object accordingly. However, I don't want to go this route because I will have to update the library everything I add a new event type.

I want it to determine the field to be used for the type parameter looking at the `event.DESCRIPTOR.full_name` and figure out the corresponding field from the data proto

How can I do this in python?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated?csw=1#oneof ?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question without answer, but I faced the same problem and solved in this way, so I hope it can help future reader:

You can dynamically access all the oneof fields and check which event type matches the corresponding field and return the oneof field name

```py
def get_field_name(event):
    for field in data.DESCRIPTOR.oneofs[0].fields:
        if event.DESCRIPTOR.full_name == field.message_type.full_name:
            return field.name  # will return server.login, server.register or server.delete
```

Then, we can do:

```py
data_obj = data()
field = get_field_name(event)
getattr(data_obj, field).CopyFrom(event)
```